# Get historical data for Garbage collection

Tags: java, java-8

Is there any way to monitor garbage collection and see historical data to know which objects were cleaned and when? I could not find any documentation about it.

Comment: The problem with your request is that ordinary objects are not “cleaned”. Most GC operations work by retaining the reachable objects, making every other memory area available implicitly, regardless of whether or how many object lived there before. Tracking the life time of every object would imply a large overhead, which would distort the result anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot monitor on per-object basis when they were cleaned. GC logging provides only per region amounts and their changes with each GC event. The only built-in option for having historical view on GC events are GC log files. See e.g. [here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/understanding-garbage-collection-logs)